# Integrating multiprocessing.Process with concurrent.future._base.Future

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I have a requirement of creating child processes, receive results using Future and then kill some of them when required.

For this I have subclassed multiprocessing.Process class and return a Future object from the start() method.

The problem is that I am not able to receive the result in the cb() function as it never gets called.

Please help/suggest if this can be done in some other way or something I am missing in my current implementation?

Following is my current approach

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from concurrent.futures import _base
import threading
from time import sleep


def foo(x,q):
    print('result {}'.format(x*x))
    result = x*x
    sleep(5)
    q.put(result)


class MyProcess(Process):

    def __init__(self, target, args):
        super().__init__()
        self.target = target
        self.args = args
        self.f = _base.Future()

    def run(self):
        q = Queue()
        worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.target, args=(self.args+ (q,)))
        worker_thread.start()
        r = q.get(block=True)
        print('setting result {}'.format(r))
        self.f.set_result(result=r)
        print('done setting result')

    def start(self):
        f = _base.Future()
        run_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
        run_thread.start()
        return f


def cb(future):
    print('received result in callback {}'.format(future))


def main():
    p1 = MyProcess(target=foo, args=(2,))
    f = p1.start()
    f.add_done_callback(fn=cb)

    sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()

    print('Main thread dying')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your start method you create a new Future which you then return. This is a different future then the one you set the result on, this future is just not used at all. Try:

```
def start(self):
    run_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
    run_thread.start()
    return self.f
```

However there are more problems with your code. You override the `start` method of the process, replacing it with execution on a worker thread, therefore actually bypassing multiprocessing. Also you shouldn't import the `_base` module, that is an implementation detail as seen from the leading underscore. You should import `concurrent.futures.Future` (it's the same class, but through public API).

This really uses multiprocessing:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from concurrent.futures import Future
import threading
from time import sleep


def foo(x,q):
    print('result {}'.format(x*x))
    result = x*x
    sleep(5)
    q.put(result)

class MyProcess(Process):

    def __init__(self, target, args):
        super().__init__()
        self.target = target
        self.args = args
        self.f = Future()

    def run(self):
        q = Queue()
        worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.target, args=(self.args+ (q,)))
        worker_thread.start()
        r = q.get(block=True)
        print('setting result {}'.format(r))
        self.f.set_result(result=r)
        print('done setting result')

def cb(future):
    print('received result in callback {}: {}'.format(future, future.result()))

def main():
    p1 = MyProcess(target=foo, args=(2,))
    p1.f.add_done_callback(fn=cb)
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
    sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print('Main thread dying')
```

And you're already in a new process now, spawning a worker thread to execute your target function shouldn't really be necessary, you could just execute your target function directly instead. Should the target function raise an Exception you wouldn't know about it, your callback will only be called on success. So if you fix that, then you're left with:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from concurrent.futures import Future
import threading
from time import sleep


def foo(x):
    print('result {}'.format(x*x))
    result = x*x
    sleep(5)
    return result

class MyProcess(Process):

    def __init__(self, target, args):
        super().__init__()
        self.target = target
        self.args = args
        self.f = Future()

    def run(self):
        try:
            r = self.target(*self.args)
            print('setting result {}'.format(r))
            self.f.set_result(result=r)
            print('done setting result')
        except Exception as ex:
            self.f.set_exception(ex)

def cb(future):
    print('received result in callback {}: {}'.format(future, future.result()))

def main():
    p1 = MyProcess(target=foo, args=(2,))
    p1.f.add_done_callback(fn=cb)
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
    sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print('Main thread dying')
```

This is basically what a `ProcessPoolExecutor` does.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This was a really silly mistake. Thanks for noticing! :)